# Counting intersections of rectilinear lattices

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

The following proposition

*Let $g>0$ be an integer and let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^g$ be a rectilinear lattice (possibly shifted) with mesh $d$ at most $D$. Then we have
$$
\left| \#(\Lambda \cap V_g) - \frac{\text{volume } V_g}{\text{covolume } \Lambda} \right| \leq c(g,D)\frac{d}{\text{covolume } \Lambda}
$$
for some constant $c(g,D)$ depending only on $g$ and $D$ which can be explicitly computed. (We will not need the explicit computation in this paper.)*

is used in a paper of Joshua Holden (http://www.numdam.org/article/JTNB_2004__16_1_173_0.pdf), it is a slightely generalized proposition from

Stephen A. DiPippo, Everett W. Howe; Real Polynomials with All Roots on the Unit Circle and Abelian Varieties over Finite Fields; Journal of Number Theory, Volume 73, Issue 2, 1998, Pages 426-450. (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X98923022)

Do you know how to compute this constant? More precisely, if we have 
$$
\lim_{D\rightarrow\infty} \frac{c(g,D)}{kD^N} = 1
$$
for some constants $k$ and $N$, do you know how to compute this constant $N$?